# How to specify a argument output of pipe as input to script?

Tags: bash, shell

How to specify the piped argument as input to a script which I am willing to run?

For example, I have tried this command:

```
ls -1U | grep "txt" | ./my script.bash
```

… but the output, after piped, is expecting to be run as:

```
./myscript.bash a.txt

./myscript.bash b.txt
```

… and so on.

Can anyone tell me how to specify the argument here?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `xargs` with your current command :

```
ls -1U | grep txt | xargs -n 1 ./my_script.bash
```

However, the best solution is to replace the whole command with `find` :

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec ./my_script.bash {} \;
```

This is better because it avoids parsing the output of `ls`, a process that is prone to errors.

In both cases the `./my_script.bash` command is executed once by record. If you can and want to invoke the script with multiple files as arguments, remove the `-n 1` from the `xargs` execution or replace the `\;` of the `find` execution by `+`.

Answer (score 0):

**Case1. No dependency on external program**

```
for filename in *.txt;do
    ./my_script.bash "$filename"
done
```

**Case2. Use of pipe** : variable *filename* exists in child process(subshell)

```
ls -1U | grep txt | while read filename;do
    ./my_script.bash "$filename"
done
```

**Case3. Use of pipe** : variable *filename* exists in current process

```
while read filename;do
    ./my_script.bash "$filename"
done < <(ls -1U | grep txt)
```